# Gerrit api to know last log by file name

Tags: git, github, github-api, gerrit

We are using gerrit for code review . I am developing a external tools which should takes input as file name and gives last five commit user name . Is there any REST api available in gerrit to achieve this .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at some examples following.

Show the last 5 changes owned by user USER:

```
curl -s --user GERRIT-USER:GERRIT-PASS --request GET "https://GERRIT-SERVER/a/changes/?q=owner:USER&n=5" | sed 1d | jq --raw-output '.[]._number'
```

Show the last 5 changes on file PATH/FILE:

```
curl -s --user GERRIT-USER:GERRIT-PASS --request GET "https://GERRIT-SERVER/a/changes/?q=file:PATH/FILE&n=5" | sed 1d | jq --raw-output '.[]._number'
```

Comment: How to know on particular file ?

Comment: I added more info in the answer.